# Python splitting list/array in kth item and non-kth item

Tags: python, list, slice

Suppose

```
x = range(20)
k = 5
x_kth = x[::5]
```

That gives me `0,5,10,15 etc`
Is there any easy way to get the non kth elements in x?

```
x_nonkth = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11 etc
```

I know I can do

```
x_nonkth = [x[i] for i in range(len(x)) if i%k]
```

But I am looking for an easier way (and possibly faster?) if there is any.

Comment: Well I fell in love with slicing and I was hoping there was something easier and faster than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `set` difference: -

```
>>> x = range(20)
>>> k = 5
>>> list(set(x) - set(x[::k]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Comment: This will be useful in the future if I need to remove items from a set, thanks. But it runs slightly slower than the one above and is just as long.

Comment: Picking this as my answer, albeit not as fast or short as I had expected it taught me a new thing that is very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

You can be a little more Pythonic by using `enumerate`. Apart from that, that list comprehension it's pretty much the definition of what you want:

```
>>> lst = range(20)
>>> [e for i, e in enumerate(lst) if i % 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

An alternate approach would be to take slices and chain them, but I wouldn't consider that easier (could be faster if `k` is large and the list is long):

```
from itertools import islice, chain

def without_kth(lst, k):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(
        islice(lst, i+1, i+k) for i in range(0, len(lst), k)
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `del x[::5]` to delete every fifth element in the list.  It will mutate the original list, so if you want a new list, be sure to copy the list first and then use the mutation, e,g

```
>>> y = x[:]
>>> del y[::5]
>>> print y
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```